# Video takes too much to load and play

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have build this website https://medicinalcannabisofgeorgia.com/home and the problem is that my home page has a video and it takes so much time to play. its not bad on pc but in mobile browser its very slow. What should do to make it faster?

```
<video className="videoTag" loop autoPlay muted playsInline>
        <source src={require("../../media/sample.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
```

Comment: I am not sure about the `require`. Can you try something like `src="https://medicinalcannabisofgeorgia.com/files/videos/sample.mp4"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you could use a more compressed video file
2. provide preload="none" to the video tag
3. provide a poster="thumbnail.png" that loads before the video

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 2):

`require` loads the whole file in memory, hence the delay. You should use [`video`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) standalone or combined with [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) to take advantage of media buffering (which `require` does not):

```
<video src="link/to/video.mp4">
  Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>

<video>
  <source src="link/to/video.mp4">
  Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```